# Calendar Bug with Android / Cordova: Button Widgets ("Cancel", "Set") not appearing

Tags: android, cordova

Device:
Samsung Galaxy S10, Android version 12

Issue: When I test on 10 different android devices the calendar looks correct, however on this one device I cannot book an appointment because the "Cancel" and "Select" widgets are not appearing.

Code:

```
<input type="date" value="2022-02-24">
```

No custom font or colour scheme changes - regular date tag

[See image for missing calendar buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we1A0.png)

Comment: you should give  full code of  date picker..

Comment: I think the code it's ok, it's just pure html only.. the problem is how some android devices change the colour of the date picker..

Comment: @NiajMahmud <input type="date" value="2022-02-24"> Nothing special about the code, I think this bug is on the device in the OS somehow, I have not been able to replicate it on any other device.